# JUNIT not identifying resources under src/test folder

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am using the below code in my junit to fetch files from test/resources folder

```
new ClassPathResource(xmlFileName).getFile();
```

However I see the below error -

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
     at [Source: C:\Users\V12839\Workspaces\C-Test\c-service\bin\mock\CResponse\CResponse_1.json; line: 1, column: 1]

java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [mock/CResponse/CResponse_1.json] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:48)
```

I am running the test using spring test suite. The path shown in the error \bin\mock , however my test is under \src\test\resources

Comment: Well, how do you expect us to help you with so few information to deal with?

Comment: sorry ,just wanted to check if this method of fetching file from classpath is incorrect. This seems to be working in other project of mine. I can share additional that is required. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use classLoader like this :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("somefile").getFile());
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks Ivan! I tried this and I see the below being printed - C:\Users\V12839\Workspaces\C-Test\c-service\bin\mock\CResponse\CResponse_1.json. However I have placed the files under C:\Users\V12839\Workspaces\C-Test\c-service\src\test\resources\CResponse\CResponse_1.json

Comment: Yes, when the program is running the bin folder is the resorce folder.

Comment: Is there a way to look up file under test resources? I have another project which looks it up correctly with the same code. i am trying to see the differences , but so far couldn't find anything related.